# javascript httpobserver vs eventlistener

Tags: javascript, listener, observers

I built a web filter in firefox using a listener and an observer.  I am finding that it is unpredictable which will be used when the user goes to a page or remote content is called in for a page.  If I type an address into the address bar, sometimes the listener will be called, and sometimes the observer.  How can I get better control?  What fires one over the other?  If I knew the "driving" page the user actually went to, I could alter how I handle "called" content based on filtering decisions.

listener:

```
var pageLoaded = {
 init: function() {
     var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
     if(appcontent) { appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pageLoaded.onPageLoad, true); }
},
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
// doc is document that triggered "onload" event
var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
// do stuff here
}
```

observer:

```
function httpObserver() { this.register(); }
httpObserver.prototype = {
    observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
     try{
      subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
      // do stuff here
     }
    }
}
```